# Removing Item from Combobox without Firing Change Event

Tags: vba, events, combobox

I am creating a userform in Word VBA that only has one combobox named `cboType` and one command button named `cmdNext`. In default, `cboType` have `Null` value and `cmdNext` is disabled.

I use `cboType_Change` event so that when an item is selected from the combobox, `cmdNext` is enabled and the combobox value is stored to a variable `Type`. However, I have another sub that will remove each item in `cboType` when `cmdNext` is clicked. I find out that removing item also fire the `cboType_Change`. I don't want this to happen because it will also change the value in variable `Type`.

In order to overcome this, I have tried using `cboType_AfterUpdate` event instead of `cboType_Change`, but I found out that this event will be fired only if the focus moved from `cboType` (cmiiw). Meanwhile, I don't have any other active/enabled control in the userform, so the `cboType_AfterUpdate` event won't be fired (the combobox value won't be stored to variable `Type` and `cmdNext` won't be enabled).

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the function to be called, can't you use

```
Call cboType_AfterUpdate()
```

to call this manually when the user clicks the `cmdNext` button?
Not sure if this solves your initial problem that `cboType_Change` is called when you change some value in the combobox.